# Draw a straight line on the screen in Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, line-drawing

I am making a game in which you shoot a ball. I want there to be a line that follows your finger when you touch the screen (showing you the path the ball will travel). It needs to be straight, and also a little side question:

Once the line is drawn, is there a way to detect if it collides with a sprite? So, if the line hits a wall, it won't go through it? Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for drawing only a line you can use `ccDrawLine` function and you can change line color using `glcolor4f` you can also change line width using `glLineWidth` but iprefer to use these functions for debug purpose. it's better if you try some sprites drawing for accual game.

for collision testing I suggest you use box2D and create body(and fixture) for both line and moving sprites. you can edit fixtures you created when ball changes position.